# Change color of jQueryUI dialog close X

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a jQueryUI Dialog, but the X to close it is the same color as the background.  How could I change it.  I've used the jqueryUI CSS hosted on their site, and it works, so it must be my jQuery theme.  I have a live example at http://www.tapmeister.com/dialog/, and the code is listed below.  Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-dialog-titlebar { border:0; background:none; color:#000000; }
        </style> 

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready( function() {$("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: true});});
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="dialog" title="Title">Hi There!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image color is white: http://www.tapmeister.com/dialog/css/ui-lightness/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png

Open the file in Photoshop or some other photo editing program. Then do a color overlay to the color you want. In Photoshop it would be "menu > layer > layer style > color overlay". Save, then upload file.

It may be better just to use your existing orange image. Just use CSS opacity.

```
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}

.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

This way there will be one less image called.

EDIT:

Find Code:

```
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);
}
```

Replace With:

```
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}

.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Comment: What was confusing me was firebug saying failed to load url of the image.

Comment: "filter: alpha(opacity=40);" is correct, but that's for IE. "opacity: 0.4;" is for other browsers.

Comment: you say it doesn't work, what's not working? I looked at your intial example to try and debug, but I see the code hasn't been added. You need to replace the old code with what I posted.

Comment: I edited my post showing what code needed to be replaced with what I originally posted.

Comment: Thanks Xarcell. Your right, it works. I first just put your new CSS in the main file, firebug showed it as overwriting the CSS in jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css, but evidently  something else is happening. I am having a little difficult time understanding sprites.  The link you posted showing ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png showed it as white, but only because .decoded {background-color: #FFFFFF;color: #222222;}.  I also tried changing from ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png" to ui-icons_222222_256x240.png" in the main file, but didn't get the results I was expecting.  Can you help explain what is going on?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  An explanation would be extra appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Line 262:

```
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
 background-image: url("images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png");
}
```

You need to add a new image to this sprite (or as a new image completely) which is the color you want.

Comment: I've never worked with sprites before.  I seem to have several of them in the directory.  ui-icons_222222_256x240 is black, and should work.  What would be the best way to just change from using ui-icons_ffffff_256x240 and use ui-icons_222222_256x240