# define the border of ui-widget-content in the jquery modal dialoge

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two modals on one page. The border for the first is defined in the `jquery.ui.theme.css` file in the `.ui-widget-content` class.

Is there a way to append a style attribute and overwrite the one defined by the css file?

I want the second modal to have a different color border.

**Here is my div:**

```html
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Discharge Warning">
    <p>Are you sure you want to discharge this Patient</p>
</div>
```

**Here is the jQuery for my second modal:**

```js
$('#dialog-modal').dialog(
{
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable:false,
    show:
    {
        effect:"blind",
        duration:500
    },
    buttons: 
    {
        'discharge': 
        {
            text: 'Discharge Patient',
            click: function () { $('#DischargeReferralForm').submit(); },
            class: 'btn purple',
            style: 'font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
        }
    },

});

$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane')
    .find('button:contains("Discharge")')
    .prepend('<i class="icon-ok"></i>');

$('#DischargeMgs').click(function () { $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open"); });
```

***FYI:** The page inspect trace's the color back to the ui-widget-content class.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843647/change-color-of-jqueryui-dialog-close-x

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308369/jquery-ui-dialog-individual-css-styling

May be these can give you some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a closer look at **[jQuery UI Dialog individual CSS styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308369/)** and added to my css file:

```
.ui-dialog-content1
{
    border-color:#6d1b81 !important;
}
```

and to my jquery file:

```
dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-content1'
```